# Compiling a C program with Clang for MIPS (32-bit) on a FreeBSD x86_64/AMD64 system

Tags: freebsd, c, cross-compilation, mips, clang

Is there a way to compile a C program with Clang compiler for MIPS (32-bit) on a FreeBSD x86_64/AMD64 system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If FreeBSD supports some Linux cross-compiler tools(and you can port them to FreeBSD if they doesn't exists in their repositories) then probably yes. It is not FreeBSD tool but i know one tool with Linux distro that can build cross-compilers from source and switch between compiler relatively easy is crossdev from Gentoo Linux. I suggest you installing Gentoo if you want to do any sort of compiling (cross or built-in) and then when compiled with Gentoo linux you can copy and paste your package to your FreeBSD.